# i have 2 dropdownlists which are binded to each other but

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

my 2nd dropdownlist is select financial year has years associated with it and when i am trying to select and year like 2011-2012 its not showing its value on button click instead its changing my selection to 1st one that is 2010-2011 same is happening if i select any other project code from my 1st dropdown i m able to select the 1st value in 2nd dropdownlist not the 2nd item?.....[whats happening is my 2nd dropdown which is showing values linked to my1st dropdownlist is not letting me select its 2nd value and submit if i m selecting the 2 nd value its automatically changing it to 1st value and displaying the result ?]

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;


    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                string query = "select * from project";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");

                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            con.Close();

        }




        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                string query1 = "Select * from yearly where pid = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(ds);
                DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;

                DropDownList2.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();

                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");

                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            con.Close();
        }



        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select pcode,fyyear,date,salary,ta,contigency,nrc,institcharges,others from monthly where pcode=('" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ) AND fyyear=('" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')",con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }



        }



    }

i am also attaching aspx code:

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/grid.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="yearwiseex.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Project Code"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
           Height="20px" Width="130px"
           onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Financial Year"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            Height="20px" Width="130px"></asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 82px" 
            Width="90%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    &nbsp;<br />
        </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question properly? We cannot assume and help.

Comment: ill try its like this suppose i hav 2 dropdownlist in my 1st list i have pcode(project code) and in the other i have fyyear(financial year associated with the pcode). so what happens normally is when i select item from pcode list my 2nd dropdown is automatically populated with financial years

Comment: continued...like suppose pcode is abc/21 when i select this the other dropdown will be filled with years like 2010-2011,2011-2012etc. ok so now when i want to display result in gridview by selecting items from dropdowns whats happening is i select abc/21 years come i select 1st value from 2nd dropdown click submit result shown ...but when i select to see data for 2nd financial year and i select it in the dropdown and hit submit button it shows result for the previous fyyear only and also it changes my selection in 2nd dropdown also

Comment: Cascading DropDownList questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net]+cascading+dropdownlists+-jquery&submit=search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for MultiSelect. In that case, use a listbox:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx

...and set the selection mode to "Multiple".

Comment: no i dont want multiselect...ok i will explain: seei have 2 dropdownlist and both are databind my 1st dropdownlist contains project codes and my 2nd dropdownlist contains financial years associated with the project code .so what i want is when i select a project code from 1st dropdown the other dropdown shows financial years associated with that project code...that part i am able to do but when i select a project code and my 2nd dropdown list has more that 2 or 3 items and i try to select the 2nd item its not showing result for that instead its changing my selection to 1st financial year.